# UITableView Null Value

Tags: swift

I have a list of JSON data downloaded from server:

### (DataModal.swift)

```
class DataModal {

   var orderAutoid: Int?
   var orderId: String?
   var orderName: String?
   var orderQty: String?
   var orderStatus: String?

init(bOrder_autoid: Int, bOrder_id: String, bOrder_name: String, bOrder_qty: String, bOrder_status: String){
    self.orderAutoid = bOrder_autoid
    self.orderId = bOrder_id
    self.orderName = bOrder_name
    self.orderQty = bOrder_qty
    self.orderStatus = bOrder_status
}
```

### (OrderStructureDownloadProtocol.swift)

```
protocol OrderStructureDownloadProtocol: class {
func newItemDownload(items: Array<Any>)
}

....

    var jsonElement = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    var newOrders = Array<Any>()

    for i in 0..<jsonResult.count {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! Dictionary

        let newOrder_autoid = jsonElement["orderAutoid"] as? Int ?? 0
        let newOrder_id = jsonElement["orderId"] as? String ?? ""
        let newOrder_name = jsonElement["orderName"] as? String ?? ""
        let newOrder_qty = jsonElement["orderQty"] as? String ?? ""
        let newOrder_status = jsonElement["orderStatus"] as? String ?? ""

        let newOrder = BMSDataModal(bOrder_autoid: newOrder_autoid, bOrder_id: newOrder_id, bOrder_name: newOrder_name, bOrder_qty: newOrder_qty, bOrder_status: newOrder_status)

        newOrders.append(newOrder)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async (
        execute: { () -> Void in
            self.delegate.newItemDownload(items: newOrders as! Array<Any>)
    })
```

### (tableview.swift)

```
var newOrdersArray = [BMSDataModal]()

func newItemDownload(items: Array<Any>) {
    newOrdersArray = items as! [BMSDataModal]
        newOrderLookupTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

### (tableview.swift another part)

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "orderLookupCell", for: indexPath) as! NewOrderTableViewCell

let item = newOrdersArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.newHMNumber?.text = item.orderId ?? "-"
    cell.newMP?.text = item.orderName ?? "-"
    cell.newQTY?.text = item.orderQty ?? "-"

    return cell
}
```

---

having all the old `NS`-style changed. The app is running okay, there are some items that need to reset. As my data-source always contain `Double`, but I declared it as a `String`, as I won't deal with calculation so I treated it as 'String'.

Comment: Is `newOrder.Order_autoid = newOrder_autoid` called? If not, you'll be loading empties values, no ?

Comment: 1. Why are you `DataModel` properties declared as implicitly unwrapped? 2. Please follow standard naming conventions using `lowerCamelCase` for variable names. 3. Why does `DataModel` extend `NSObject`? 4. Don't use `NS[Mutable]Dictionary` or `NS[Mutable]Array` in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary and Swift array.

Comment: It's most likely a type mismatch. You are creating new (empty) objects even if the multiple `if let` check fails. By the way don't use `NS(Mutable)...` collection types in Swift at all, conform to the naming convention (lowerCamelCased variable names and uppercased class names) and don't declare properties IUO as an alibi not to write an initializer (if you remove the `?? "-"` the code will certainly crash).

Comment: Yes. As `jsonElement["Order_autoid"]` = `newOrder_autoid` = `newOrder.Order_autoid`. Shall I use the same name by the way?

Comment: check if control even goes inside the if statement with a print ??

Comment: you are mixing up objective-c data type with swift data type. NSMutableArray and Array is not inter changeable. If you really want to keep the NSMutableArray part, you have to pass NSMutableArray and loop through each object and then add it to  `newOrdersArray`. You cant just type cast as a whole.

Comment: @rmaddy which method should I use instead of `NSDictionary`? just `Dictionary`?

Comment: @Ken Yes, use `Dictionary` (or the more typical short syntax of `[ KeyType : ValueType ]`).